# How to change border color of checkboxes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I am learning how to do form validation on various types of elements and want to do this in only Javascript. I have some checkboxes here and a Javascript function that checks if the checkboxes has at least one option selected on form submission. Basically the checkboxes should show up red if no option is selected. But I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'borderColor' of undefined

```js
function validate() {
  var ok = true;
  var yes = document.getElementById("yes").checked
  var no = document.getElementById("no").checked;

  if (!yes && !no) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(".btn-group").style.borderColor = "red";
  }

  return ok;
}
```

```html
<div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn active">
    <input id = "yes" type="checkbox" name="box" value="yes" />
    </i>Yes
  </label>

  <label class="btn active">
    <input id = "no" type="checkbox" name="box" value="no" />No
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I commend you for attempting this in pure JS!

Comment: Consider using a radio instead of a checkbox.

Comment: `document.getElementById ` get elements by its `id` attribute, not its `value`. So try `<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="no" id="yes" />`, or alternatively, try `document.querySelector('input[value="yes"]')`Also, theres an `<i>` tag on the loose.

Comment: I the id originally! I forgot to write them here before

Comment: @Neal I do not want to use a radio box because multiple options can be selected

Comment: @DanielShillcock sorry I am new but how is this not pure Javascript

Comment: @jebmarcus here is a fancy css answer: https://jsfiddle.net/maniator/uacotpno/ idk if it is what you want, bc if it is ill make it an answer.

Comment: DanielShillshock said it _was_ pure javascript. A couple more notes: `getElementsByClassName` return an list of elements, so to select the first result you need to use `getElementsByClassName(...)[0]`.

Comment: @jebmarcus It is pure Javascript :) I was making the point that it is often tempting to make use of helper libraries for form validation

Comment: @Neal sorry but i am doing form validation, and in javascript. Your answer just changes the css

Comment: @jebmarcus you can still do the form validation in js. I am just saying the colors etc can all be done in CSS :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems there:

1. If you use `getElementsByClassName` you should use the classname without the dot.
2. The `style` property is for the element (while `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of the elements).
3. If you only set the color of the border (and not the style and the width) there will be no border.

Here is the correction:

```js
function validate() {
  var ok = true;
  var yes = document.getElementById("yes").checked
  var no = document.getElementById("no").checked;

  if (!yes && !no) {
    ok = false;
    document.getElementsByClassName("btn-group")[0].style.border = '1px solid red';
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("btn-group")[0].style.border = '';
  }
  return ok;
}
```

```html
<div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn active">
    <input id = "yes" type="checkbox" name="box" value="yes" />
    Yes
  </label>

  <label class="btn active">
    <input id = "no" type="checkbox" name="box" value="no" />No
  </label>
</div>

<button onclick="validate()">Validate</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName()` Returns a collection of elements, so you need to iterate over the result to make sure you apply the style change to each element.

Furthermore, you need to use the `element.setAttribute()` method to change the style like so:

```
element.setAttribute("style","border-color: red");
```

Combining those two things should get you the result you want.

Edit: you don't *have* to use `setAttribute()` if you don't want to, as Neal pointed out. The important thing to take away is that you need to iterate over your collection.

Edit 2:
Looking at your code again, I noticed that when you call `document.getElementsByClassName(".btn-group").style.borderColor = "red";`, you're not retrieving the check boxes, you're getting a collection of `divs` of class `btn-group`, so you're actually attempting to set the border color *of the div* to be red, not the check boxes. You're also always returning `true` unconditionally at the end of `validate()`.

If you're only checking these 2 check boxes, you can just simply use the `id`'s to change them:

```
function validate() {
  var ok = true;
  var yes = document.getElementById("yes").checked
  var no = document.getElementById("no").checked;

  if (!yes && !no) {
    document.getElementById("yes").setAttribute("style","border-color: red");
    document.getElementById("no").setAttribute("style","border-color: red");
    // no checkbox selected, validation should fail and return false
    return !ok;
  } else {
    // checkbox selected, validation should pass and return true
    return ok;
  }
}
```

Comment: No need for setAttribute.

Comment: The first part of your answer is correct though :-)

Comment: I've been doing java for too long and am set in the ways of using mutators, but yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You should add or remove a class to the button group in order to hide show the border. Just add or remove the class when validation changes.

Also, you need to either iterate over all the button group classes or choose one.

***Note:*** I used the class methods from [You Might Not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

```js
function validate() {
  var btnGroups = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-group");

  for (var i = 0; i < btnGroups.length; i++) {
    var btnGroup = btnGroups[i];
    var yes = document.getElementById("yes")['checked'] == true;
    var no = document.getElementById("no")['checked'] == true;

    if (!yes && !no) {
      if (!hasClass(btnGroup, 'invalid')) addClass(btnGroup, 'invalid');
      return false;
    } else {
      if (hasClass(btnGroup, 'invalid')) removeClass(btnGroup, 'invalid');
    }
  }

  return true;
}

function hasClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList) return el.classList.contains(className);
  else return new RegExp('(^| )' + className + '( |$)', 'gi').test(el.className);
}

function addClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList) el.classList.add(className);
  else el.className += ' ' + className;
}

function removeClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList) el.classList.remove(className);
  else el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + className.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
}
```

```css
.btn-group.invalid {
  border : thin solid red;
}
```

```html
<div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn active">
    <input type="checkbox" id="yes" name="box" value="yes" onchange="validate()" />Yes
  </label>

  <label class="btn active">
    <input type="checkbox" id="no" name="box" value="no" onchange="validate()" />No
  </label>
</div>
```